# How to encode any CSV data in JMETER and will use that as input parameter ${}

Tags: csv, jmeter

[image]

[image]
How to encode input filed "fileData"(from CSV) and use it as input parameter like ${fileData}

below is the ex-
fileData input should be converted like=

{"fileData":"QkVOLCxIb21lQmFuajc2MjkxNzI2MTcxOTU0MjI1OTQ5ODkxNjIzMjI0ODUyODI3NjI5MTcyNjE3MTk1NDIyNTk0OTg5MTYyMzIyNDg1MjgyQVZJMSwsSG9tZUJhbmtqNjI5MTcyNjE3MTk1NDIyNTk0OTg5MTYyMzIyNDg1MjgyNzYyOTE3MjYxNzE5NTQyMjU5NDk4OTE2MjMyMjQ4NVJFQ09SREEsLGFkZHJlc3MsLCwsLCwsLCwsLERTQVMyLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLFksLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLE4sLCwsLCwsLCwsLERTQVMyLCwsQ0=="

POST data:
{"fileData":""${fileData}","fileName":"JMETER1.txt","fileDescription":"testing file upload with single data","isEncrypted":"N","encryptionDetails":{"algorithm":"","secretKey":"","signatureBytes":""},"valMode":"N"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode the data from your CSV file in [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

There is [__base64Encode() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) which can do the trick for you:

[image]

Your request syntax should look like:

```
{
  "fileData": "${__base64Encode(${fileData},)}",
  "fileName": "JMETER1.txt",
  "fileDescription": "testingfileuploadwithsingledata",
  "isEncrypted": "N",
  "encryptionDetails": {
    "algorithm": "",
    "secretKey": "",
    "signatureBytes": ""
  },
  "valMode": "N"
}
```

[image]

and variable substitution will happen in the runtime:

[image]

You can install __base64Encode() function along with other [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#Custom-JMeter-Functions) using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

[image]

Comment: Hi @Dmitri  , for me file data is not coming proper as it is in shown in function helper - coming like "fileData": "IkJFTjs=",
but expected:-QkVOLCxIb3BlQmFua05vbkZpbmFuLCxIb21lQmFua05GRiwsYWRkcmVzcywsLCwsLCwsLCwsU0JBQ0MxMiwsQixOTiwsLEcsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsWSwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsTiwsLCwsLCwsLCwsU0JBQ0MxMiwsLCwsOw==

Comment: the data is truncating when i called from csv file, how can i resolve that any configuration is missing from CSV data set config elment like delimiter etc...please help